Can't import other package in nested workspaces in Rust project
I have the following project structure:
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── lib1
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── lib2
    ├── Cargo.lock
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── pyproject.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs

Here are some files' contents:
Cargo.toml:
[workspace]
resolver = "2"
members = ["lib1", "lib2"]

lib1/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "lib1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "lib1"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
pyo3 = "0.22.0"

lib2/Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "lib2"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "lib2"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
pyo3 = "0.22.0"
lib1 = {path = "../lib1"}

In lib1/src/lib.rs, I've defined a function, which I'd like to import in lib2. But, if I run
maturin develop

from lib2, then I get
$ maturin develop
 Found pyo3 bindings
 Found CPython 3.11 at /home/ignoring_gravity/nested-pyo3-example/.venv/bin/python
 Using build options features from pyproject.toml
   Compiling lib2 v0.1.0 (/home/ignoring_gravity/nested-pyo3-example/lib2)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `lib1`
 --> lib2/src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use lib1::sum_as_strings;
  |     ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `lib1`
  |
help: there is a crate or module with a similar name
  |
2 | use lib2::sum_as_strings;
  |     ~~~~

What am I doing wrong / missing?

From what I can tell, it should work. Please share the relevant code of both libs. For example, is the function you defined in lib1 public?

@ninjadev64 Summarizing from the linked duplicate - you cannot use a crate-type = ["cdylib"] library as a cargo dependency. To make this work, "lib" (or "rlib") needs to be added to the crate-type array.
